# Inserting in SQLite Table Gives Crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

My application crashed when i insert the data in SQLite Database.

My code of Inserting Data in SQLite Database is

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrNewFriendsId count]; i++) {

NSString *stQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO NewFriendsTable (friend_id,friend_fullname) VALUES ('%@','%@')",[arrNewFriendsId objectAtIndex:i],[arrNewFriendsFullName objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"Query registered NewFriendsTable : %@",stQuery);
    if (sqlite3_open([appdelegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql =[stQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [[arrNewFriendsId objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 3, [[arrNewFriendsFullName objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            NSLog(@"insert successfully NewFriendsTable ");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"insert not successfully NewFriendsTable ");

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);


}}
```

In above code the app got crashed on this line

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);
```

The Data Inserted is Coming From FaceBook and the Insert Query is

```
INSERT INTO NewFriendsTable (friend_id,friend_fullname) VALUES ('100000564063540','Rãhüł Pâtęł')
```

I don't get the problem.
I think it's related to `Rãhüł Pâtęł`. Because it's not regular character.

but then also don't know that this is the exact problem.
any advice, tutorial, code, link will be great help.

Comment: offtopic: i would recommend you to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Comment: My application is very big and it's just another application of FaceBook with lots of more functionality. so, "FMDB" may consume more time. is there any way to solve the issue with existing thing ?

Comment: cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding remove only this..check answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is within your code.

Why you are using:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [[arrNewFriendsId objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 3, [[arrNewFriendsFullName objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Because you already have the values in the query itself.

You need to remove those statements.

Use like:

```
for (int i=0; i<[arrNewFriendsId count]; i++)
{
    NSString *stQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO NewFriendsTable (friend_id,friend_fullname) VALUES ('%@','%@')",[arrNewFriendsId objectAtIndex:i],[arrNewFriendsFullName objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"Query registered NewFriendsTable : %@",stQuery);
    if (sqlite3_open([appdelegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql =[stQuery UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
           if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
           {
               NSLog(@"insert successfully NewFriendsTable ");
           }
           else
           {
              NSLog(@"insert not successfully NewFriendsTable ");
           }
           sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, especially with non-ASCII characters.
   All strings used with SQLite *must* be UTF-8.
2. To use parameters, you actually must have parameter markers in the query:

   ```
   "INSERT INTO NewFriendsTable (friend_id,friend_fullname) VALUES (?,?)"
   ```

   (This automatically gets rid of formatting problems.)
3. You *must* check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.
4. The two parameter numbers are `1` and `2`, not `1` and `3`.
5. You must call `sqlite3_bind_text` *before* calling `sqlite3_step`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` with `UTF8String`.

```
const char *sql =[stQuery UTF8String];
```

Nice [Tutorial](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/09/sqlite-in-objective-c.html) on database

Answer (score 0):

You are taking `%@` for facebook id in below line and it is for `String`. and i hope, your facebook id field type in database is not `integer`.

```
 NSString *stQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO NewFriendsTable (friend_id,friend_fullname) VALUES ('%@','%@')",[arrNewFriendsId objectAtIndex:i],[arrNewFriendsFullName objectAtIndex:i]];
```

You can try below if your facebook id field is not `integer`.

```
 sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrNewFriendsId objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
 sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 3, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrNewFriendsFullName objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```